# Place two tikz nodes next to each other

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can one change the font/fontfamily for the text of a tikz node? I can't seem to find it anywhere.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\ttfamily]    
\node[text centered, color=white, rotate=-90, shape=rectangle, fill=black,
   font=\huge, inner sep=3pt,minimum height=1cm] at (0,0) {\textbf{Some Text}}
    ...Another node goes here that is "snapped" to the next one along one of its
    sides and not hard coded...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I'd like to put some text right next to the first node without having to hard code the distance(as some text may change)

Comment: If you would like to change the font in whole tikz block, you can use \ttfamily just after the \begin{}, without [].

Comment: I can't seem to change the font family  and font size independently.

Comment: Please add a minimal working example that illustrates your problem. That would clear the confusion about the possible cause of the undesired behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*TikZ* is very well integrated to *TeX* and you can use the same methods to modify some texts. For example you can use TeX's groups outside the tikzpicture environment or inside. You can use specific options inside a tikzpicture environment or inside a node. The main rule is that the text inside a node used the font defined outside if you don't use a specific option to change the font.

Now to put some text right the main node, you can use `label= ...` to define a label node or you can use the `positioning` library or you can use `anchor=`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fourier,tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}  
  Font  by default

\begingroup 
\ttfamily\small
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {Text in he node};
\end{tikzpicture} 

After the \emph{tikzpicture} but inside the group. 
\endgroup

Outside the  \verb+tikzpicture+ and outside the group.

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[font=\huge\bfseries] {Text in he node};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begingroup \bfseries\small
  \node {First node};
   \endgroup  
  \node at (0,-1) {Second node}; 
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,label={[align=left]right:right label\\ok}] {Main label};
\end{tikzpicture} 

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] (main){Main label}; 
  \node[right=0pt of main] (sub){Sub label};
\end{tikzpicture} 

 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] (main){Main label}; 
  \node[anchor=west] at (main.east){Sub label};
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]